# Python requests hide the parameters passed in the url

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a set of data passed to the POST method:

```
    url = 'https://exmaple.com/gate'
    payload = {
        'Client': '4444',
        'Total': '10.99',
        'Currency': 'EUR',
        'Order': '12345',
    r = requests.post(url, params=payload)
    response = '$window.location.href="{}";'.format(r.url)
    return response
```

Then I get this url:

```
https://exmaple.com/gate?Client=4444&Total=10.99&Currency=EUR&Order=12345
```

How can I hide the parameters passed in the url?

Comment: Why do you want to hide them?

Comment: You probably want to do `data=payload` instead of [`params`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls).

Comment: @Alex Lucaci, I have to hide it because it requires operator.

Answer (score 1):

Depending if the API accepts it you should send the parameters in the body of the request, not as params of the url, like this:

`r = requests.post(url, data=payload)`

When you do it like that, nobody (usually) will be able to see the data you send

Comment: If I use : r = requests.post(url, data=payload), it redirects me to a clean url but without data sent by post.

Comment: That means the API is not designed for your use case of hiding the data you send.

Comment: this API is designed for hiding data in the url. It works in PHP but i cannot handle with python.